# I need help wth "wp-login.php script causing core dump"

Tags: wordpress, malware

All I know is there is a script causing a dump on wp-login.php. I had the host do a restore, I changed the password, I disabled all plugins but it still keeps on dumping and now all my space is full. I can delete the core files but that fills up quickly. If there is anyone here willing to help me in exchange for some work, I'm open.

As for the malware scan, nothing comes up, I've tried, wordfence and a few others as well as have InMotion due to a scan.

There's still potential that malware could linger in other places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting a fresh copy of the Core and fresh copies of `all` plugins, then check each plugins support forums for vulnerabilities, that may point towards a culprit. Also check your theme support for the same.

Essentially replace everything but `.htaccess`, `wp-config` and any custom theme code.